# What can I use (Design pattern maybe?) to avoid this ISP violation? with a Asp.net basepage

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I have a class:

```
class BasePage
{
   protected abstract Company ReferencedCompany
   {
      get;
   }
}
```

And an asp.net page that inherits from it. However i do not want/need to implement this property in the inheriting class. And I dont really want to leave it blank. Is there a design pattern I can use to avoid this clear violation of the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) (ISP)?

Also I cant re-factor the entire code base so I was looking for something I could throw in the way. The adapter pattern perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have more types. If some page doesn't have a `ReferencedCompany` then that page **is not** a BasePage. See an example below:

```
class BasePage
{
   //something common to ALL pages   
}

class CompanyPage : BasePage
{
   protected abstract Company ReferencedCompany
   {
      get;
   }
}

class EmployeePage : BasePage
{
   protected abstract IEnumerable<Employee> AllEmployees
   {
      get;
   }
}
```

If you use this with ASP.NET WebForms consider using MVP pattern, it cleanly separates view model and presenter.